# Dataflow - BigQuery autodetect?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am facing with a problem in Dataflow. I used Python BigQuery API, and it works fine with autodetect. It run fine, job_config create table and at the same time append values:

```
...
job_config = bigquery.LoadJobConfig()
job_config.autodetect = True
job_config.create_disposition = 'CREATE_IF_NEEDED',
job_config.source_format = 'CSV',
job_config.field_delimiter = '|',
job_config.skip_leading_rows = 1

load_job = client.load_table_from_uri(
            uri,
            table_id,
            location=region,
            job_config=job_config,)
```

So, I need to use Dataflow, to scale transfer from gcs to BigQuery, but, I don't find resources on how to use autodetect in writetobigquery apache beam.

```
 class DataIngestion:
    def parse_method(self, string_input):
        values = re.split(",",
                          re.sub('\r\n', '', re.sub(u'"', '', string_input)))
        row = dict(
            zip(('date', 'volume', 'open', 'close', 'high', 'low', 'adjclose'),
                values))
        return row
...

    (p
     | 'Read from a File' >> beam.io.ReadFromText(known_args.input, 
                                                  skip_header_lines=1)
     | 'String To BigQuery Row' >>
     beam.Map(lambda s: data_ingestion.parse_method(s))
     #| 'Parse file' >> beam.Map(parse_file)
     | 'Write to BigQuery' >> beam.io.WriteToBigQuery(
             known_args.output,
             custom_gcs_temp_location="gs://XXXX",
             create_disposition = "CREATE_IF_NEEDED",
             write_disposition = "WRITE_APPEND"))
    p.run().wait_until_finish()
```

So, I have parse_method too, but I tried to run return only values without dict...

Comment: Values passed to `WriteToBigQuery` should be in the for of a dict `{"column_name": value...}`. Maybe you can find more info in the sink docs https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.28.0/apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.html?highlight=writetobigquery#apache_beam.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteToBigQuery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing `schema='SCHEMA_AUTODETECT'` to the PTransform. That should enable it.

Comment: It works, I add SCHEMA_AUTODETECT parameters I have to extract column names from csv in bucket and add them to the parser.

Comment: What I try before, is to use auto detect without specify schema name like bigquery python api. So if you have any idea on how to use autodetect without put manually column name. I read csv from gcs, but the load is hudge if we have a XXGB file.

Comment: @Pablo Does `'SCHEMA_AUTODETECT'` account for `RECORD` and `REPEATED` fields?